# does foreach (<$IN>) slurp the file?

Tags: perl, foreach, io

Looking over some recent questions, I saw the following awkward construction:

```
open my $IN, "<", 'file' or die "can't read from 'file'. $!";
foreach my $line (<$IN>) {
    ...
}
```

(The idiom I'm familiar with is `while (my $line = <$IN>) {...}`.)

My question is, does the `foreach` idiom force the `<>` into list context, and hence demand that the interpreter slurp the entire file?

Comment: Yes, it does...  I'm unsure how to elaborate on that!

Comment: It's called list context and has nothing to do with arrays, but yes.

Comment: thanks for the "answers." (edited "array context" -> "list context")

Comment: I wouldn't call `for (<$IN>)` an idiom but rather bad practice. Even when one needs the whole file content upfront (legitimate) I think that it's better to read them into an array and `for` over that.

Comment: I came across it in questions written by people who clearly don't know what they're doing.

Comment: @flies: I think **zdim** is talking about your *"I saw the following idiom"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

The list expressions of a foreach loop is evaluated in list context. There are a couple of optimizations (e.g. `for ($x..$y)` and `for (@a)` uses "no" memory), but `for (readline($FH))` is not optimized.